# rails.vim installed but :Rfind doesnt'work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, rails.vim

I've installed rails.vim and it seems to be installed correctly since `:Rails!` returns `rails.vim 5.0`.

But, if I'm in an existing Rails project and look for a file `:Rfind user` I get `E492: Not an editor command: Rfind user`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not work in empty buffer, when you open any file in your Rails directory and then give any Rails.vim command it would work. And i am not sure about the *Rfind* command in Rails.vim

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work neither...

Comment: Now i opened the help text from Rails.vim found the solution. Try `find` instead of Rfind, it would work. `:Rfind [{file}]         Obsolete alias for :find.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `Rfind`, it would work.

From the help page of Rails.vim `:h Rails`

```
 :Rfind [{file}] Obsolete alias for :find.
```